# Changing main of a C++ project without using the -nostartfiles option

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, linker

On a given C++ project, I'm trying to change the main to my newEntry.cpp:

```
void entry(){
...
}
```

According to some online posts, to do that, you should use these linker options:

```
-e entry newEntry.cpp -nostartfiles
```

The -e "symbol" "file" gives the new main file to the linker and the -nostartfiles omits the crt* file so that it doesn't provide the actual main.

The problem is that there is a hidden symbol _dso_handler defined in the crt.*, so by doing using this approach, you end up with this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:75: undefined reference to `__dso_handle'
```

The -nostartfiles is causing a new issue here. How could I solve that ? 
 
I could try to provide the _dso_handle (I don't how) but I'm suspecting new errors coming from the fact that the crt* file is omitted. I read on some posts that using the -nostartfiles to change the entry point of a C/C++ project is obsolete today.

So is there another way to change the main of my project ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot do simply `int main() { entry(); }`?

Comment: Yes, I'm facing a segfault when I run the actual main.

Comment: Actualy `main` is not the entry point. Rather this is a symbol `_start`. This function performs initializations of member of crt* files (data needed for dynamic linkage as __dso_handle, dynamic initialization of static variables, data for thread local managment etc...). After these initializations are performed, it calls main, and after main returns, it perform clean-up. So probably don't want to change the entry point! What you need is to somehow rename the symbol `main` or performed an interposition of `main` (it is referenced in `crt1.so`).

Comment: So either you recompile the source file of crt1.so (it is defined in glibc I suppose). Or maybe a linker script may do the job or things that a magician linker guru I am not will be able to do.

Comment: Finaly I found out in glibc/sysdeps../start.S that you can provides your"entry points" that will be executed before main and after during process initialization. Here a good explanation: http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html

Comment: Very interesting, thank you @Oliv !
So we can actually add our own constructors in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just found what is certainly the most convenient solution: using ld to *wrap* main, demo:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int __real_main(int argc,char* argv[]);//other name for main
extern "C" int __wrap_main(int argc,char* argv[]){//called in place of main
   std::cout << "Executing " << argv[0] << std::endl;
   int ret = __real_main(argc,argv);
   std::cout << "main returned " << ret << std::endl;
   return ret;
   }
 int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
   std::cout << "Main execution" << std::endl;
   return 42;
   }
```

Compile with linker option `--wrap=main` wihth `c++ -Wl,--wrap=main file.cpp`. Voilà!

[Live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b41cd891f9d6078)